# Why is the highlighted result wrapped in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

When adding the highlight option to the query, why is the highlighted text wrapped in an array? I need to do this in the view:

```
<%= link_to question.highlight.description[0].html_safe, question_path(question.id) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because elasticsearch returns you an array of highlights it found.

Comment: Ah...so if the text is long it can contain more highlights?